# How do I set GDB output to stderr?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug, with `gdb -batch`, a program in the middle of a filter pipeline. The problem is that `gdb` outputs to stdout, which is mixed into the programs output, and not logged.

How to change GDB's output to stderr so it ends up in the log?

Comment: Is running  gdb separately and having it attach to the program (either with `attach` or via gdbserver) acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change GDB's output to stderr so it ends up in the log?

I don't know any way to *change* GDB's output without modifying source code, but you can *copy* GDB's output to stderr or whatever other log file with a pair of commands:

```
(gdb) set logging file /dev/stderr 
(gdb) set logging on 
Copying output to /dev/stderr.
```

Together with `-batch` option this can be done in one line:

```
gdb -ex "set logging file /dev/stderr" -ex "set logging on" -batch
```